# Word sequence using apriori

Tags: python, apriori

I have implemented Apriori to find the repeating sequence of letters but what i want to do is find the repeating words. My output gives me all the letters count. But, i want the word count;

i/p
    data = ["i am donald trump","i am donald duck"]

o/p
    --> {'d ': 3, ' d': 3, 'on': 3, 'ld': 3, 'am': 3, 'do': 3, 'al': 3, 'na'}

-->what i wanted ->
 i: 2

am: 2

trump: 2

donald: 3

i am: 2

am donald: 2

donald trump: 1

i am donald: 2

```
import re
import unittest
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

class Apriori(dict):

    def __init__(self, listOfSequences, support):

        Args:
            listOfSequences (list): A list of strings, each letter representing a specific event.
            support (int): The minimum percentage of sequences a pattern must match.
        """

        super(Apriori, self).__init__()
        self.data = listOfSequences
        self.thres = (support * len(self.data)) / 100.0
        self.primitives = self.getPrimitives()
        self.apriori()
        del self.data

    def apriori(self):
        candidates = self.getNewCandidates(self.primitives)
        while len(candidates) > 0:
            res = self.getPatternsCount(candidates)
            self.update(res)
            candidates = self.getNewCandidates(res.keys())

    def getPrimitives(self):
        primitives = set()
        for seq in self.data:
            for event in seq:
                primitives.add(event)
        return primitives

    def getNewCandidates(self, candidates):
        newCandidates = set()
        for seq in self.data:
            for can in candidates:
                for subs in re.findall(can + ".", seq):
                    newCandidates.add(subs)
        return newCandidates

    def getPatternsCount(self, candidates):
        patternsCount = defaultdict(int)
        for seq in self.data:
            for can in candidates:
                if can in seq:
                    patternsCount[can] += 1
        return {k: v for k, v in patternsCount.items() if v > self.thres}


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pass
```

Run:

```
import csv
from ne import *

#print(t)
data = ["i am donald trump","i am donald duck"]
#print(data.type())

patterns= Apriori(data,15)

print(patterns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on your specific question (and ignoring some issues in your posted code), you can achieve what you want by simply splitting the input strings and maintaining frequency counts for those split tokens.

For example, using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

data = ["i am donald trump","i am donald duck"]
c = Counter()
for seq in data:
    c += Counter(seq.split(' '))

print c  # Counter({'i': 2, 'donald': 2, 'am': 2, 'trump': 1, 'duck': 1})
```

p.s. And then you probably won't be interested in the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) values, but in those that surpassed a certain threshold, like:

```
print {(k,v) for k,v in c.iteritems() if v >= 2}  # {('am', 2), ('donald', 2), ('i', 2)}
```

Comment: This will not give me the count of i am donald Trump:1 and what you have given is just it counts the word. I am doing here is also to find sequence of words.

Comment: My answer was for the original question. I see now that you've edited it after my answer, so of course now the answer needs adaptation as well.

Comment: May be now i have explained it in brief. sorry